# How can I optimize the 5-layer loop using functions provided by torch?

Tags: pytorch, vectorization

`x` is the tensor with the shape of (16, 10, 4, 25, 53), `y` has the same size as `x`.
`mean`'s shape is (25, 53), the size of `jc` and `ac` are both (16, 10, 4).

How can I optimize the following expression with torch functions?

```
for k in range(x.size()[0]):
    for s in range(x.size()[1]):
        for u in range(x.size()[2]):
            for i in range(x.size()[3]):
                for j in range(x.size()[4]):
                    num1 += (x[k][s][u][i][j] - mean[i][j] - jc[k][s][u]) * (y[k][s][u][i][j] - mean[i][j] - ac[k][s][u])
                    num2 += (y[k][s][u][i][j] - mean[i][j] - jc[k][s][u]) ** 2
                    num3 += (y[k][s][u][i][j] - mean[i][j] - ac[k][s][u]) ** 2
```

Comment: `num2` should have `x` instead of `y` in its expression?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking at [broadcasting](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) your tensors along singleton dimensions.
First, you need the *number* of dimensions to be the same, so if `mean` is of shape `(25,53)` then `mean[None, None, None, ...]` is of shape `(1, 1, 1, 25, 53)` - you did not change anything in the underlying data, but the *number* of dimensions is now 5 instead of only 2 and these singleton dimensions can be broadcast to the corresponding dimensions of `x` and `y`.

An optimized code using broadcasting will look something like:

```py
num1 = ((x - mean[None, None, None, ...] - jc[..., None, None]) * (y - mean[None, None, None, ...] - ac[..., None, None])).sum()
num2 = ((y - mean[None, None, None, ...] - jc[..., None, None]) ** 2).sum()  # shouldn't it be x here?
num3 = ((y - mean[None, None, None, ...] - ac[..., None, None]) ** 2).sum()
```